# How to fix 'int object is not iterable' from a function

Tags: python

I have a dict() like so

```
{'2020': [51000, 15000, 16000, 13000, 12000, 31000, 20000, 23000], '2021': [16000, 13000, 5000, 20000, 25000, 23000, 14000]}
```

and I want to run this function

```
def report(x,k):
    for v in x.values():
        the_sum = sum(v)
        the_num = len(v)
    for k,v in x.items():
        if the_sum % the_num == 0:
            x[k] = the_sum/the_num
        else:
            x[k] = the_sum//the_num
    return x[k}
```

so that I can find the average of the value in the dict(), but I only got the average for '2020'
and I got this error for the '2021'

```
the_sum = sum(v)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: The indentation is not correct. Can you fix the indentation format in the question?

Comment: Perhaps not the cause of this error, but `for k,v in x.items()` overwrites the function argument `k`.

Comment: `x[k}` is a syntax error. Please make a [mre] including the call to `report()` and the expected output, as well as the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're iterating over all of the key-value pairs if you're only trying to calculate the average for one key (as the function signature states).

If you want to compute the average value for a value, given a key and a dictionary, you can do the following:

```py
data = {'2020': [51000, 15000, 16000, 13000, 12000, 31000, 20000, 23000], '2021': [16000, 13000, 5000, 20000, 25000, 23000, 14000]}

def report(x, k):
    return sum(x[k]) // len(x[k])
print(report(data, '2020'))
```